# What is wrong with the loop function in this code?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I use an excel macro to automate the FAA (Federal Aviation Administration) Notice Criteria filing process. Essentially we have to fill out the information on the webpage, click submit, and print out the result page into a PDF.

When I run the main module from Excel; It opens the FAA page (https://oeaaa.faa.gov/oeaaa/external/gisTools/gisAction.jsp?action=showNoNoticeRequiredToolForm) on Internet Explorer to fill out the form, return the results/run time back to Excel, and save the result page as pdf file to the selected folder. The first structure is processed smoothly, but the loop stops after the first PDF download and does not repeat.

Any idea what's wrong with the loop function? Any help would be appreciated!

Below is the main module;

```
Sub Main()
Dim IE As Object
Dim website As String
Dim PDFPath As String, PDFfolder As String, PDFName As String
Dim i As Long
Dim curprinter As String
Dim outdatetime As Date
Dim structure As String
Dim GE As Double, SH As Double
'*** clear Hyper Links ****
Sheets("Main").Range("L2:N100000").ClearContents

'**** request to print to PDF Files ****'
If Cells(13, "Q") = True Then

    'Set the default printer to Adobe PDF (for Adobe Professional).
    'SetDefaultPrinter "Adobe PDF"
    
    If Left(Application.ActivePrinter, 9) <> "Adobe PDF" Then
        MsgBox "Please set Adobe PDF as default printer! exit now. The name of the active printer is " & Application.ActivePrinter
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Check if the PDF's folder exists.
    If Sheets("Main").Range("Q11").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please select a folder to save PDF by click on the [Select PDF Folder] button or enter path to Cell: Q11. Exit Now."
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf FolderExists(Sheets("Main").Range("Q11").Value) = False Then
        MsgBox "The folder: " & Sheets("Main").Range("Q11").Value & " is not valid. Exit now."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    PDFfolder = Sheets("Main").Range("Q11").Value
    If Right(PDFfolder, 1) <> "\" Then PDFfolder = PDFfolder & "\" 'Add the backslash if not exists.
End If
 
website = "https://oeaaa.faa.gov/oeaaa/external/gisTools/gisAction.jsp?action=showNoNoticeRequiredToolForm"

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
i = 2

Do While Cells(i, "D") <> ""

    IE.Navigate website

    While IE.busy
        DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
    Wend
    
    While IE.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
    
    IE.Visible = True
    TxtHtml = IE.Document.getElementById("latDir").innerhtml

    IE.Document.getElementById("latD").Value = Cells(i, "D")
    IE.Document.getElementById("latM").Value = Cells(i, "E")
    IE.Document.getElementById("latS").Value = Round(Cells(i, "F"), 2)
    
    IE.Document.getElementById("longD").Value = Cells(i, "G")
    IE.Document.getElementById("longM").Value = Cells(i, "H")
    IE.Document.getElementById("longS").Value = Round(Cells(i, "I"), 2)
    
    If Int(Cells(i, "J")) = Cells(i, "J") Then
        IE.Document.getElementById("siteElevation").Value = Cells(i, "J")
    Else
        IE.Document.getElementById("siteElevation").Value = Int(Cells(i, "J")) + 1
    End If
    
    If Int(Cells(i, "K")) = Cells(i, "K") Then
        IE.Document.getElementById("unadjustedAgl").Value = Cells(i, "K")
         IE.Document.getElementById("structureHeight").Value = Cells(i, "K")
    Else
        IE.Document.getElementById("unadjustedAgl").Value = Int(Cells(i, "K")) + 1
        IE.Document.getElementById("structureHeight").Value = Int(Cells(i, "K")) + 1
    End If
    
    IE.Document.getElementById("latDir").Value = "N"
    IE.Document.getElementById("longDir").Value = "W"
    
    '**********Change the 2-letter value below to modify the "Traverseway" input on the Notice Criteria Tool Website*************************
    IE.Document.getElementById("traverseway").Value = "NO"
    'Options: "NO"-No Traverseway, "IH"-Interstate Highway, "OT"-Other Traverseway, "PR"-Private Road, "PH"-Public Roadway, "RR"-Railroad, "WW"-Waterway
    '****************************************************************************************************************************************
    
    IE.Document.getElementById("traverseway").FireEvent ("onchange")
    
    Set x = IE.Document.GetElementsByName("submit")
    x(0).Click
    
    '***********CODE-ORIGINAL - ************'
    'IE.Document.getelementbyid("submit").Click
    
    Do While IE.busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    a = IE.Document.body.innerhtml
    aa = InStr(1, a, "Results")
    If aa > 0 Then
        newstring = Mid(a, aa + 7, 250)
        If InStr(newstring, "You do not exceed Notice Criteria.") > 0 Then
            file = "False"
        Else
            With CreateObject("htmlfile")
                .Open
                .write newstring
                .Close
                file = .body.outerText
            End With
        End If
    End If

    Cells(i, "M") = file
    outdatetime = Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy  h:mm:ss")
    Cells(i, "N") = Format(outdatetime, "MM/dd/yyyy  h:mm:ss")
    
    If Cells(13, "Q") = True And Left(Application.ActivePrinter, 9) = "Adobe PDF" Then
    
        '**** PDF file name & path ****'
        PDFName = "Structure " & removeSpecial(Sheets("Main").Range("C" & i).Value) & " " & Format(outdatetime, "YYYYMMDD") & ".PDF"
        PDFPath = PDFfolder & PDFName
        '**** Delete the PDF if it already exists  ****'
        If Dir(PDFPath) = PDFName Then Kill (PDFPath)

        '*** structure number to add to PDF file ***'
        structure = "Structure # " & Cells(i, "C")
        
TryAgain:
        'Wait for 2 seconds to let IE load the document
        fTime = Timer
        Do While fTime > Timer - 2
          DoEvents
        Loop
        
        eQuery = IE.QueryStatusWB(6)
        If eQuery And 2 Then
        
            IE.ExecWB OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER
            Call PDFPrint(PDFPath, structure)
           
            fTime = Timer
            Do While fTime > Timer - 2
                DoEvents
                Loop
         Else
           GoTo TryAgain
         End If

        '*** create HyperLink to each PDF File ***'
        With Sheets("Main")
            .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("L" & i), Address:=PDFPath, TextToDisplay:="Link to PDF"
        End With
 
    End If

i = i + 1
Loop

Set IE = Nothing

Call UnWrapM

MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code to see where it fails?

Comment: I think there might be something wrong with ` eQuery = IE.QueryStatusWB(6)`

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: @TimWilliams That's what the debug suggested

Comment: Please be more explicit - how did it "suggest" that?  There's no code in that main loop to exit the loop, so what happens when you run it in debug mode?

Comment: @TimWilliams May I send you the excel sheet? This is all pretty new to me, wish I could explain it to you but I'm just kind of stumbling around